# Why does JS seem to empty the microtasks queue before the closing </script> tag?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, event-loop, script-tag

While looking at this code:

```html
<script>
    console.log(1);
    new Promise(r=>r()).then(() => console.log(2));
</script><script>
    console.log(3);
</script>
```

it seems like 2 should be printed **after** 3, because it should have been queued as a microtask, just like it behaves here:

```html
    <script>
        console.log(1);
        new Promise(r=>r()).then(() => console.log(2));
        console.log(3);
    </script>
```

I can't find a good explanation - why would the JS engine bother to empty the microtask queue before continuing to process the next script element?

Comment: Why? The first is two different script tags, so the browser's going to parse and run them separately (it'll parse and run the first script, _then_ parse and run the next. You're not loading the script as external file with `async` behaviour, so you're stuck with classic synchronous "your script is going to block further DOM parsing until it's done" behaviour) whereas in the second one we're only dealing with a single script, and that last console log runs before the promise is handled.

Comment: I expect promises to behave asynchronously. why would it behave differently than setTimeout?

Comment: It is behaving asynchronousely. It's just done _well_ before the second script tag has finished getting parsed and executed.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Admittedly, "*you're stuck with classic synchronous behaviour*" is a reason to believe it would be executed the same as in the second snippet. But yeah, they're really just two queued macrotasks.

Comment: @Bergi I don't think there is any task being queued here. IIRC it's all part of the parsing algorithm at this point, so (from the event-loop POV) it's actually all synchronous, even the microtask checkpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the JS engine but the DOM one, which after [running a classic script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#run-a-classic-script) has to [clean up after running a script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script) (step 8). This *clean up* algorithm does a microtask checkpoint.

> 3. If the [JavaScript execution context stack](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#execution-context-stack) is now empty, [perform a microtask checkpoint](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#perform-a-microtask-checkpoint).

So the microtask isn't really checked "before" the `</script>` end tag, but rather right after the script got executed (which technically happens when the end tag is met).

You can even make some funky stuff like forcing a MutationObserver to notify of changes in the DOM right in the middle of parsing an element's content <sub>This can come handy for testing.</sub>:

```html
<script>
  function myObserver(mutationsList) {
    for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
      for (let n of mutation.addedNodes) {
        if (n.id === 'parent') {
          console.log("innerHTML: ", n.innerHTML);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var observer = new MutationObserver(myObserver);
  observer.observe(document.body, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  });
</script>
<div id="parent">
  <span>This will be parsed</span>
  <script>/* This script forces the MutationObserver to kick its notifications */</script>
  <span>Not yet parsed</span>
</div>
```